# Can't send email using action mailer from server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Just don't get it. All three (in desperation) of my environment files are identical and look like this: That's environment.rb, test.rb and development.rb

```
Drivetastic::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "gmail.com" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "me@gmail.com",
    password: "secret"
  }

#  config.action_mailer.async = true
  ###

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
#  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

When I send an email through action_mailer, it sends the email perfectly! When I upload the application to a server and do the same thing, I get this:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in MessagesController#create
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvCQ
```

Here's my log:

```
Started POST "/messages" for 2.12.109.89 at 2013-11-19 08:54:37 -0500
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6Fr5xsg8Gn/mjc8Pxtl6wdfV/wfJAybNjAKgMIB0t+g=", "message"=>{"name"=>"12345", "town"=>"abcdef", "email"=>"iiiiiiix", "content"=>"yep"}, "commit"=>"$
  Rendered contactform/contact.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered contactform/contact.text.erb (0.0ms)

Sent mail to me@gmail.com (12.6ms)
Date: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 08:54:37 -0500
From: me@gmail.com
To: me@gmail.com
Message-ID: <528b6d9dcd60c_73792a055e4422e6@HAL9000.mail>
Subject: 12345 is trying to reach you! (from Drivetastic.com)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_528b6d9dcbaef_73792a055e442183";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_528b6d9dcbaef_73792a055e442183
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ContactForm#contact

Email from potential student!

, find me in app/views/app/views/contact_form/contact.text.erb

----==_mimepart_528b6d9dcbaef_73792a055e442183
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://w=
ww.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
<body>
Note: This is an automated message! No one will read any replies you send=
 to it! To reach the contact, email . If you have any problems, email Jul=
ian at. </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_528b6d9dcbaef_73792a055e442183--

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Not much help from the log. So annoying, don't know why this would happen. Identical project works locally, same environment.

I can log in and out of gmail just fine...no recaptcha stuff, nothing.

** UPDATE **

Okay, so I think this is a problem with my vps. It's running Ubuntu. Bit of a noob in this area, but can you suggest what could do this? Should I configure my firewall? Open a port? What should I do?

As for this question being closed minded, Ubuntu + Nginx + Rails is pretty widely used I think.

Comment: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):` your server is not allowed to talk to whatever you are calling in line 17

Comment: right, thanks. So that means I need to talk to my provider? Or is this a problem with gmail? In which case am I screwed?

Comment: By server what do you mean? My application server? (Puma, Passenger whatever)

Comment: I think he means the machine your application is running on

Comment: THought as much, that jargon does get confusing though :P (application server, web server, virtual server, physical server (as in server))

Comment: Type `iptables -L` to check firewall rules. Also consult gmail's docs about reverse DNS issues. Your vps hosting provider may also have a firewall, you should be able to change the configuration through their web interface.